# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release on AWS

Tags: 18.04, amazon-ec2

Does anyone know when Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be deployable on AWS Market Place ?

Comment: I sent a support request to canonical about this a few days ago, but haven't gotten a reply

Comment: Yeah I also logged 2 tickets with them few days ago no reply either.

Answer (score 10):

It is, see https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ for reference depending on what region you are in.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. So Ubuntu 18.04 have been released but under the community AIMs area. But the description reads: Canonical, Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS, UNSUPPORTED daily amd64 bionic image. What does UNSUPPORTED mean ?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed today that my 16.04 LTS EC2 instances now show this message when logging in via ssh:

```
New release '18.04.1 LTS' available
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Comment: I noticed this as well but have been reluctant to run the upgrade until I see there's an AWS-supplied 18.04.1 LTS available.  That said, what one could do is create an instance from 16.04, bring it up through 18.04.1 and then create a custom AMI for future instances.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on AWS and it is available in free tier.
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07CQ33QKV?ref=cns_srchrow

Hopefully it is also per second billed (I still don't know how to check it for sure aside from billing).